# Apply function by column with several inputs in matlab

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

Apply a function over a matrix using several columns as arguments to apply function with several imputs.

```
A = [1 2 3];
B = [4 5 6];
C = [7 8 9];

% This is the function I want use,
bsxfun(@(x,y,z) 1/(sqrt(2*pi*z)) * exp((-(x-y).^2)/(2*z)), A, B, C)
```

But is not working, only works with two imputs:

```
bsxfun(@(x,y) x+y, A, B)
```

The error ouput of bsxfun is:

```
error: Invalid call to bsxfun.  Correct usage is:

 -- bsxfun (F, A, B)
```

which is telling that i can not do this with more than 2 inputs..

The expected calculation of the function is basically:

```
[1/(sqrt(2*pi*C1))*exp((-(A1-B1).^2)/(2*C1))
    1/(sqrt(2*pi*C2))*exp((-(A2-B2).^2)/(2*C2))
    1/(sqrt(2*pi*C3))*exp((-(A3-B3).^2)/(2*C3))]
```

being `A1,B1,C1` the first element of `A,B,C` respectively to N being N the number of elements of the vectors(with same length)

```
result = [ 0.079 0.08 0.08 ]
```

Comment: Done, syntax edited, expected result and error explained. thx for the revision :)

Comment: Using Octave, but I hope to use it in matlab, they have the same syntax in this case of problem? I will update the post once run this in my matlab software.

Comment: Perfect, so I will modify the warning to matlab warning because it would be my development environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `bsxfun` here. You just need to define the function handle appropriately.

```
f =  @(x,y,z) 1./(sqrt(2*pi*z)).*exp((-(x-y).^2)./(2*z));
```

Now your expected result is:

```
f(A,B,C)
```

Comment: great! I didnt know about this way to solve it, Im coming from python, thanks!